# Upgraded tomcat 7 to tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, apache, maven, tomcat

When I upgraded my tomcat from 7 to 8.5 and tried to run my application, I getting below set of errors from stdferr.log.

Am I doing any mistakes? I have copied all remaining jars from tomcat7(mismatched). Please guide me in resolving this issue

Here is the error logs:

```
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat8.5/lib/jaxb-Jul 27, 2017 12:27:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
        WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat8.5/lib/saaj-api.jar] from classloader hierarchy
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat8.5\lib\saaj-api.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

        Jul 27, 2017 12:27:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
        WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat8.5/lib/saaj-impl.jar] from classloader hierarchy
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat8.5\lib\saaj-impl.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)


    Jul 27, 2017 12:27:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
    WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat8.5/lib/jsr173_api.jar] from classloader hierarchy
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat8.5\lib\jsr173_api.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)


    Jul 27, 2017 12:27:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
    WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat8.5/lib/sjsxp.jar] from classloader hierarchy
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat8.5\lib\sjsxp.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

    Jul 27, 2017 12:27:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
    WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat8.5/lib/woodstox.jar] from classloader hierarchy
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat8.5\lib\woodstox.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)


    Jul 27, 2017 12:27:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
    WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat8.5/lib/resolver.jar] from classloader hierarchy
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat8.5\lib\resolver.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)


    Jul 27, 2017 12:27:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
    WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat8.5/lib/jaxb-impl.jar] from classloader hierarchy
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat8.5\lib\jaxb-impl.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

    Jul 27, 2017 12:27:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
    WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat8.5/lib/stax-ex.jar] from classloader hierarchy
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat8.5\lib\stax-ex.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)


    Jul 27, 2017 12:27:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
    WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat8.5/lib/streambuffer.jar] from classloader hierarchy
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat8.5\lib\streambuffer.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)


    Jul 27, 2017 12:27:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
    WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat8.5/lib/stax-utils.jar] from classloader hierarchy
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat8.5\lib\stax-utils.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)


    Jul 27, 2017 12:27:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
    WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat8.5/lib/schema/weblogic-container-binding.jar] from classloader hierarchy
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat8.5\lib\schema\weblogic-container-binding.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:60)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:338)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:288)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1898)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1126)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1842)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: it states that you are missing schema\weblogic-container-binding.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your Tomcat context.xml file

```
<Context>
    <JarScanner scanClassPath="false" scanAllDirectories="false" />
</Context>
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain what this tag does ?